# getServerSideProps functions is not gettin called in NextJS 13

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, getserversideprops

Here is my code, console.log(data) is undefined

i read the docs and also visited many blogs

i made sure that api endpoint is working

my page is under '/app/posts/page.js'

my AllPost function is running before my gerserversideprops function

getserversideprops function is never running, unless i call it manually after defining function. But it also not solving the error. I am still getting undefined console.log and i am not receiving any props

```
const AllPosts = ({ data }) => {
    console.log(data);          //undefined
    console.log("Hello");       //hello
    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((item) => {
                return (
                    <div key={item.name}>
                        <div>{item.name}</div>
                        <p>{item.email}</p>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);

        return { props: { data } };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);

        return { props: { data} };
    }
}


//getServerSideProps   // when i call the function manually, then this function get called, but my console.log is still undefined



export default AllPosts;
```

i have seen youtube videos and used exact code in my vs code but it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

There is no `getServerSideProps` in the `app` directory. You can use it only in the `pages` directory.

In the app directory, you can directly write your server code in the server component.

```js
const AllPosts = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);

    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((item) => {
                return (
                    <div key={item.name}>
                        <div>{item.name}</div>
                        <p>{item.email}</p>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};

export default AllPosts
```